# Apex Continuation execution failed and did not start - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, continuation

I am trying to make a POST api callout from my LWC using Apex Continuation and followed similar code: [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_continuations_apex). I have created the respective Remote Site settings too. The error message I am getting is:

> {"status":500,"body":{"message":"The continuation execution failed. The actual exception is: The continuation execution did not start. Check Remote Site Settings for the callouts. It might also be a transient network problem. Please try again.."},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Server Error","errorType":"fetchResponse"}

I already ran out of all the necessary checks I can think of:

1. Verified the request JSON payload I am setting from my LWC.
2. I've saved the endpoint on Custom label and I can see it via debug log
3. Only thing I can think of from the URL is, it has the format: https://myRESTapiURL.com:11305/first/second/createpost/1.0.0.4

Having the integer(11305) in the endpoint could impact the Continuation? Anyways, I couldn't find any sources or troubleshooting mechanisms for the above error message. Can someone assist me here if faced similar issue? Or, if I am missing something silly here?

Comment: I dont think 11305 can impact but can you test another endpoint that is working just to see if it is an issue with the URL format? Have you also reviewed the [limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_continuations_limits.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was with the Remote Site settings where I had to include the endpoint as: https://myRESTapiURL.com:11305 to make API callout successful, instead of https://myRESTapiURL.com. I hope someone might get benefited with my answer if they ever had similar situation.